# Create table from Pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table from the following pivot table:

```
Declare @t VARCHAR(10)
Declare @A VARCHAR(1000)
Declare @B VARCHAR(1000)
set @A='SELECT SUBURB, Campaign_date, [Type] '
SET @B='('


SELECT @A=@A+',['+Weeks+'] as [' +Weeks+']',@B=@B+'['+Weeks+'],' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Weeks FROM [tbl_FTTH_OrdersIn_SummerCamp]) cur
-- removing last ',' from both variables
SET @B=SUBSTRING(@B,1,LEN(@B)-1)
SET @A=@A+ + ' FROM (SELECT [NAME]
      ,[TOWN]
      ,[SUBURB], [Weeks], [count], Campaign_date, [Type] FROM [dbo].[tbl_FTTH_OrdersIn_SummerCamp]) s  PIVOT (sum(Count) FOR weeks IN ' +@B+')) p ORDER BY suburb';
exec(@A);
```

How do i do it?

The query runs fine and returns results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clause INTO:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Can you combine the two queries to see the logic please?